# JavaScript dictionary value incrementing not working in nested for loop

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, for-loop, d3.js

I am reading a csv **shark.csv** with **d3.js** and I am having an issue with a nested for-loop. The csv contains data about shark attacks by continent and by year. So I want to store how many times each continent showed up in each year. This is a screenshot of **shark.csv**:

[image: csv]

and this is how I want the result to look like:
[image]

*(these are random numbers)*

I am storing the number of times each continent name showed in a specific year in a dictionary and incrementing it as such:

```
var allYears = [];

var allConti = [];

var allOccur = {};

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/proj/main/shark.csv").then(function(data) {

    // get all unique years
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (!allYears.includes(data[i].Date)) {
            allYears.push(data[i].Date);
        }
    }

    // get all unique Continents
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (!allConti.includes(data[i].Continent)) {
            allConti.push(data[i].Continent);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

        for (var j = 0; j < allYears.length; ++j) {

            for (var k = 0; k < allConti.length; ++k) {

                // if key for match between year and continent is not stored yet
                if (!(allYears[j] + " " + allConti[k] in allOccur)) {

                    //store it with value of 1
                    allOccur[allYears[j] + " " + allConti[k]] = 1;
                } else {

                    //if already stored increment it
                    allOccur[allYears[j] + " " + allConti[k]] = ++allOccur[allYears[j] + " " + allConti[k]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(allOccur);
});
```

This is basically what the code does:

1- read csv

2- store all unique years

3- store all unique continents

4- if there is no key called `allYears[j] + " " + allConti[k]` (year and continent) add it and give it a value of 1.

5- if it's already there increment its value by 1

**The issue is that all year and continent keys are ending up with a value that is the total number of rows in the csv**.

[image]

What is wrong with my for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your incrementing all values in the dictionary in each iteration of your 3rd outer for-loop `var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i`. You should instead only increment the values corresponding to the current data iteration.

Side note, `a = ++a` is redundant. You either want `a = a + 1` or `a++`/`++a`. `a++` is the most commonly seen style of incrementing a variable.

More side notes:

- prefer `let` instead of `var`
- prefer `i++` instead of `++i`
- prefer `'` instead of `"`; better yet, prefer template strings `${a} ${b}` instead of string concatenation `a + ' ' + b`
- assign a local variable for the key rather than duplicate the computation 3 times
- prefer `[].forEach` instead of traditional for-loops
- prefer `if (a[key])` instead of `if (key in a)`

```
let allYears = [];
let allConti = [];
let allOccur = {};

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/proj/main/shark.csv").then(data => {
    allYears = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.Date))];
    allConti = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.Continent))];

    data.forEach(d => {
        let key = `${d.Date} ${d.Continent}`
        allOccur[key] = allOccur[key] || 0;
        allOccur[key]++;
    });

    console.log(allOccur);
});
```

Comment: Beautiful that works. Thanks for pointing the other little stuff. Many thanks! @junvar